# Impossible to sparse or pickle DataFrame (kernel crash)

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix, pickle

The problem is very strange.

I create a pandas matrix like this:

My index is a 4 levels ones.
df = pd.Dataframe(np.zeros((300 000,300 000)), index=index, columns=index)

The matrix is built with success when I use np.zeros (without it my kernel crash) but it is impossible to pickle it or to sparse it. Python spends almost 60 Go of memory on my mac with 8 Go RAM. I also tried to use a cluster with more than 60 Go RAM. Why a so simple matrix is impossible to manage. Am I doing wrong something ?

Comment: The problem is much more how to create a sparse matrix directly to avoid to load 80 Go (or more) when my matrix is almost full of 0.

Answer (score 1):

The SparseDataFrame (SDF) are row-based. So it is a wrong way to build a SDF with a columns index.

See: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16197